# Exported files appear in a new folder and also scattered in the directory?

Tags: python, pandas

The exported files appear in these places while I' d rather to appear only scattered in the mentioned direcotry `folder`.

Observe the following as mentioned in another post.

```
import pandas
import geopandas
import os
from collections import defaultdict

folder = path.Path(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\testn")

d = defaultdict(list)
for shpfile  in glob.iglob('**/Desktop/testn/**' ,recursive = True):
    df = geopandas.read_file(shpfile) #read files
    d[os.path.basename(shpfile)].append(df)

for cat, lst in d.items():
    pd.concat(lst,sort = True).to_file(folder/cat)
```

Appears:
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw8sF.png)